# How to avoid multiple Iterations to search and assign one of the possible object property to a variable ?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

How can we avoid multiple iteration to search for an object's property and if found then assign it to a variable else search for another key ?

eq we have Video Class with one of the field as videoType which can have values as **hq(high-quality),normal(normal), def(default)**..etc and so on.

From an array containing multiple video objects, how can we search and return a particular object in an order that if the array contains object with property hq then first return it,else search for normal and proceed so on. if a set of n keys are to be tested in the key set (hq,normal,def,....) then do we always need to iterate the entire array "n" times unless the key is found.

**Can this be done is single iteration ?** Do we need to first sort the original array in the order of occurrence of the keys in desired key set. I hope my problem statement is clear.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this would be to create separate NSMutableArrays for each videoType. Then, as you iterate *once* over your array of video objects, you check its array type and add the video to the correct array.

After you finished iterating, you create the final mutable array by concatenating the other array with [`addObjectsFromArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray%3a).

If you have a lot or variable list of video types, you can create the separate mutable arrays as values in an NSDictionary, where the keys are the video types. This way, you can get the target array with one step, by fetching it from the dictionary.